# Google sheets script for exporting CSV files error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the code below but it is giving me an error:

> Exception: Argument cannot be null: content
> saveAsCSV   @ Export to CSV.gs:19

It was working before and I cannot figure out why it is not now. Help would be appreciated.

```
function saveAsCSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    // folder location
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("winspc").next();
    //delete exisiting files in folder
  var files = myFolder.getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext()){
    files.next().setTrashed(true)
  }

  for (var i = 0 ; i < sheets.length ; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    // append ".csv" extension to the sheet name
    fileName = sheet.getName() + ".csv";
    // convert all available sheet data to csv format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName, sheet);
    // create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the csv data
    myFolder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
  }
}

function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName, sheet) {
  // get available data range in the spreadsheet
  var activeRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  try {
    var data = activeRange.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined;

    // loop through the data in the range and build a string with the csv data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // join each row's columns
        // add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Are there 2 questions in your question? Q1: You want to resolve the error in your script. Q2: `is there a way to overwrite the file instead of having to delete all the files in the folder before generating the new ones?`. 2. Where is the error of ` "Exception: Argument cannot be null: content saveAsCSV @ Export to CSV.gs:19"` in your script?

Comment: The variable 'fileName' is not defined as a variable: `fileName = sheet.getName()` should be `var fileName = sheet.getName()`.  Beyond that any chance you could provide an exampe?  Your function to generate the CSV file seems overly complex as well.  You can create a CSV file simply by getting the values: `var data= activeRange.getValues()` and then `var csv = data.join("\n")`